# Best type of transportation In Brussels?

Tags: public-transport, automobiles, taxis, brussels

I'm thinking of traveling to Brussels for this holiday. I heard that public transportation in Belgium in general is great, but I'm looking for something more private. I heard about VTC Taxi and [car hires in Brussels](http://www.thecheapcarhire.co.uk/), but I'm not really sure. Can anyone recommend a method of transportation for Brussels? Thanks.

Comment: Going round by taxi can cost you more than your hotel, and way more than cheap places to stay. Try public transport if you do not have money to waste.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I was in Brussels, I signed up for [Villo](http://en.villo.be/), the city wide bike share programme.  It doesn't only cover the city centre, but goes all the way out to Anderlecht, where my hotel (with very good value for money) was located.  It's cost-effective and a very suitable way for visitors to get around.